# SSRS: How to drill though from aggregated data

Tags: reporting-services

I want to produce high level reports of aggerated data with date parameters. I would like users to be able to click on a figure to open a table report of all those in the aggerated figure.

I have heard various terms (click through, drill through, linked report) I think what I want to achieve is a 'drill trough' report.

I have created a parent and child report using the same dataset. The child report is a table with all records.

The parent report has the data aggerated in various ways i.e. COUNT(CASE_ID). The parent report has two date parameters (date_from and date_to).

I am not sure what I need to pass through to the second report to correctly filter the records. 
I have tried to pass through the dates in the parent parameter to a set of hidden parameters on the child report but this gives me the error "The 'Date_to' parameter is missing a value"

I have tried to pass through the CASE_ID however the filter insists on aggerating so I can only get FIRST(CASE_ID) or LAST(CASE_ID)

[Parent report design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPOSi.png)

[Child report design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD9BA.png)

[Parent Report Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw7PK.png)

Comment: All three things you listed are different descriptions of the same thing (click through, drill through, linked report). The other option is Drill Down where the data is in the report in hidden detail lines. Usually you'd have categories summed in the parent and the the detail of them for the Drill through/Down - like TOYS $5000 in the parent and then a breakdown of Toys in the Child that adds up to the $5000.

Comment: It may help to post a pic of your summary page to get a better idea of what you're summing.

Comment: can you show the design for both your parent report and sub-report and show what you want to click on. Also show the parameters from the sub-report. As you seem to want to pass dates as parameters, then my guess is that some date conversion is happening (or not happening) but once we see the design we may be able to help more.

Comment: I have added some screenshots. Basically I would like to be able to click on the [COUNT(Contact_ID)], lets say its 200 and see those 200 records in the child report. I would also like to be able to click on a bar in the bar chart and see those records. I am not sure if this could use the same child report or would need a different one.

Comment: You do have the parameters mapped but I don't see one with called `Date_To` in your child action (or is *Date To* just the Prompt text?). Can you run the Child report on it's own by entering dates? It seems like it should be working otherwise. For the Bar Chart, I would add another parameter to filter by the categories (Reason ID?) so the child report just displays the associated records; if filter is NULL the show all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The parameters are called Start_date and End_date. Date from and date to are prompts (sorry I can see why that would be confusing!) The child date parameters work when entering their own dates (when I make the parameters visible). The reason bar chart works with a reason_ID filter by itself however, it show all records in the dataset so similarly I need to get these date parameters figured out.